# Константа как размер массива

Tags: c++, char, const

Как задавать размер dest из примера ниже, если это будет зависеть от строки s после компиляции.
Компилятор требует константу, но строка s  будет изменять длину в процессе работы.  Компилятор должен иметь возможность определить значение выражения в точке, в которой оно используется.

```
std::string const s("Emplary");
const int len =  strlen(s.c_str());
char dest[8]; // how to change 8 on len+1????????? s - may be any lenght
strcpy(dest, s.c_str()); // Configuration Properties >> C / C++ >> Preporocessor >> Preprocessor Definitions >> _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

или

```
const char* b = &"Emplary"[0];
strcpy(dest, b);
```

нужно

```
dest[len+1];
```

Comment: 1) Использовать `std::string` / `std::vector<char>` 2) Выделять память динамически.

Comment: Кстати, `std::strcpy` в целевой массив также копирует завершающий нулевой символ. Таким образом в приведённом примере массив `dest` должен быть достаточного размера, чтобы вместить `7 + 1` символов.

Comment: ок, исправил на 8

Comment: `&"Emplary"[0];` Это круто... Вчера мне уже встречалось `&*p`. Что, кто-то новый учебник по С/С++ написал?...

Comment: В копилку: `const char* b = &[0]"Emplary";` и `const char* b = &"Emplary"<:0:>;`

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, `const char* b = &0["Emplary"];`

Comment: `char * dest = strdup(&0["Emplary"]);`...

Comment: `const char* b = bitand NULL[ "Emp" "lary":>;`

Comment: `const char* b = bitand*::std::addressof(U'\x000'[R"*(E)*""m""p""lary":>);` [Вроде работает](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28d0d104e04762aa)...

Comment: В продолжении вопроса , еще сюда гляньте плиз, ай нид хелп , так сказать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1354651/472403