# Кто разобрался что требует компилятор visual studio 2019? Предупреждение C4668

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

> Предупреждение   C4668   "**STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB**" не задано как
> макроопределение препроцессора, замена на "0" для "#if/#elif"

в справочнике написано:
Предупреждение компилятора (уровень 4) C4668
"символ" не определен в качестве макроса препроцессора и будет заменен в "директивах" на "0"
Символ, который не был определен, использовался с директивой препроцессора. Символ будет иметь значение false. Чтобы определить символ, можно использовать либо директиву #define , либо параметр компилятора /d .
Это предупреждение отключено по умолчанию. Подробнее: Выключенные по умолчанию предупреждения компилятора .

***Вопрос не в том как это игнорировать а как это исправить***

```
     #include <iostream>

int main()
{
    
    return 0;

}
```

**Предупреждение C4668 "STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB" не задано как макроопределение препроцессора, замена на "0" для "#if/#elif"**

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C2220   следующее предупреждение рассматривается как ошибка Proverka    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\limits.h   70
Предупреждение  C4668   "**STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB**" не задано как макроопределение препроцессора, замена на "0" для "#if/#elif"  Proverka    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\limits.h   70
Предупреждение  C4365   аргумент: преобразование "long" в "unsigned int", несоответствие типов со знаком и без  Proverka    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory    162
Предупреждение  C4365   аргумент: преобразование "long" в "unsigned int", несоответствие типов со знаком и без  Proverka    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory    172
Предупреждение  C4365   аргумент: преобразование "long" в "unsigned int", несоответствие типов со знаком и без  Proverka    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic 292
Предупреждение  C4365   аргумент: преобразование "long" в "unsigned int", несоответствие типов со знаком и без  Proverka    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic 308
Предупреждение  C4365   аргумент: преобразование "long" в "unsigned int", несоответствие типов со знаком и без  Proverka    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic 325
Предупреждение  C4365   аргумент: преобразование "long" в "unsigned int", несоответствие типов со знаком и без  Proverka    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\atomic 388

Comment: Покажите, как вы добились такого предупреждения — будем думать, как исправить...

Comment: да на учебе сказали все предупреждения на \Wall выставлять и обработать как ошибки, вот получил, в итоге) как это лечить я уже умер выяснять

Comment: *"на учебе сказали все предупреждения на \Wall выставлять и обработать как ошибки"* - надо же, хоть где-то пытаются учить толку

Comment: Я вот выставил все ваши ключи, написал программу `int main(){}`, и **НЕ** получил такого предупреждения. Поскольку вы *не хотите* показать, как вы получили предупреждение, исправляйте его тем, что сведите программу к показанной мною. При этом предупреждения не будет. Вас этот ответ устраивает?

Comment: щас исправлю вверху

Comment: @user7860670 Да нет, не так уж правы. При этом в VC++ получается туева хуча предупреждений в текстах самих заголовочных файлов...

Comment: Т.е. вас совершенно не беспокоят предупреждения `warning C4100: d: неиспользованный формальный параметр
warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "int"; возможна потеря данных
warning C4267: инициализация: преобразование из "size_t" в "const int"; возможна потеря данных
warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.`

Comment: `warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
warning C4189: b2: локальная переменная инициализирована, но не использована
warning C4189: b3: локальная переменная инициализирована, но не использована`? :)

Comment: `bitand NULL["Emp" "lary":> ;` Вы бы проявили хоть немного скептицизма к комментариям в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1354580) вопросе.

Comment: вот исправил!, все предупреждения на \Wall выставлять и обработать как ошибки, получаюПредупреждение C4668 "STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB" не задано как макроопределение препроцессора, замена на "0" для "#if/#elif"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку эти предупреждения появляются в *стандартных* заголовочных файлах, могу порекомендовать только отключать предупреждения на время компиляции *стандартных* заголовочных файлов. Что-то типа

```
#pragma warning(push,3)
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#pragma warning(pop)

#define lstrcat
//using namespace std;

char* string_index(int d)
```

Вот как компилируется ваш код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похоже, что выставление `/Wall` в IDE перешибает всё :), так что могу посоветовать все эти конкретные предупреждения отключать в

```
свойствах проекта -> дополнительно -> отключить указанные предупреждения
```

Но это плохо тем, что эти предупреждения будут отключены и для вашего кода.

Крайне рекомендую просто выставить уровень `/W4` — на мой взгляд, этого вполне достаточно.

Comment: `#pragma warning(push,3)
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning(pop)


int main()
{
    
    return 0;

}`
не помогает

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66408981) на EnSO.

Comment: См. картинку в моем ответе. Ваша программа, компиляция с ключиком `/Wall`.

Comment: @wololo Я бы все же не рекомендовал редефайнить какие-либо стандартные макросы. Очень уж это чревато... Типа из-за некрасивой облицовки начинать в фундаменте дома ковыряться...

Comment: Похоже, IDE перешибает все, что может. Добиться этого ы консоли я не смог, даже просто используя командную строку из свойств проекта. См. дополнение к ответу. Советую просто ограничиться `/W4`; лезть в системные заголовки и что-то в них менять — занятие предельно нездоровое!

Comment: @Harry вы оказались правы, в моем случае достаточно даже 3го уровня

Comment: У меня по жизни выставлено `/W4`, просто я уже соображаю, что можно игнорировать, а что не стоит... Мало ли, досадной описке всегда найдется место...

Answer (score 4):

Собственно проблема заключается в некорректной проверке наличия макроса `__STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__` в файле "limits.h"

```
#if __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__
    #ifndef RSIZE_MAX
        #define RSIZE_MAX (SIZE_MAX >> 1)
    #endif
#endif
```

Форма `#if ИМЯ_МАКРОСА` требует, чтобы макрос уже был определен как целочисленная константа. А если он может быть и совсем не определен, то следует предварительно проверить `#ifdef ИМЯ_МАКРОСА`. Если заголовочный файл включается, когда макрос не определен, то срабатывает резервный механизм,   Учитывая, что все предыдущие проверки в этом файле были корректные, это явно баг в стандартном заголовочном файле. На этот счет следует отправить баг репорт:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

А что же делать прямо сейчас, пока они там будут фиксить баг?

Ну во-первых можно отредактировать проблемный заголовочный файл:

```
#ifdef __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__
```

Однако редактирование этого файла требует привилегий администратора не избавит от проблемы, когда код будет собираться на другой машине. Вместо этого можно у себя в коде включать первым заголовочный файл `#include <cstdlib>`, который определяет `#define __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__ 1`. На самом деле у них там проблема еще и в том, что файл конфигурации CRT не включается в "limits.h" перед всеми этими проверками, приводя к некорректной конфигурации.

Comment: Это(включать первым заголовочный файл #include <cstdlib>) помоголо осталось xmemory 162 line ` _STL_ASSERT(_Ptr_user[-2] == _Big_allocation_sentinel, "invalid argument");` исправить Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory 162 Предупреждение C4365 аргумент: преобразование "long" в "unsigned int", несоответствие типов со знаком и без

Comment: После этого будет еще пару сотен, если не тысяч новых предупреждений... Искать на каждое свой обход? А оно ведь даже предупреждает, что "*подставляемая функция, не используемая в ссылках, была удалена*" — и так для сотен функций... Вобщем, `/Wall` в VC++ — очень неправильный уровень предупреждений...

Comment: @ВладиславValdis Честно говоря, я вот поставил себе VS 2022 и там C4365 не вылезает уже.

Comment: @user7860670 Будет теперь чем заняться)

Comment: @Harry Переходите на VS2022, там /Wall куда обузданее ведет себя. Во всяком случае, пример из вопроса собирается без особых проблем.

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо, годы берут свое, и стабильность ценится куда выше, чем новизна :) Я и так еле на 2019 переполз...

Comment: @user7860670 в vs2022 все те же ошибки [https://prnt.sc/215aid3]

Comment: @110010100 Не наблюдаю у себя таких ошибок. Убедитесь, что проект использует свежий tooset v143 (студии могут использовать инструменты от предыдущих версий) и что стандарт стоит C++17 и conformance mode.

Comment: @user7860670 [https://prnt.sc/21al28j]  и  [https://prnt.sc/21al7qm]

Comment: @user7860670 посносил вообще все пакеты в инсталлере vs =)

Comment: Все эти три файла( `limits.h`  `xmemory`  `atomic` ) находятся после переустановки по новому адресу `...\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.30818\include\` `и все также ошибки C4668 (устраняется `#define `__STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__ 1`),  C4365 (а это не устраняется, там макрос `assert` не пускает  "long" в "unsigned int")

Comment: @user7860670 В итоге мои задачи пока что не потребуют такой излишней критичности, поэтому остановлюсь на уровне 3.

Answer (score 0):

[image: имг]
У меня вот так получается, для примера скрин
вот она строка 70!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: я добавил подробностей указывает на строку 70 limits.h `#if __STDC_WANT_SECURE_LIB__
    #ifndef RSIZE_MAX
        #define RSIZE_MAX (SIZE_MAX >> 1)
    #endif
#endif
`

Comment: Забавно, что в командной строке все те же ключики дают нормальную компиляцию.... Понимаете, делать затычку на каждое предупреждение в системных заголовках при таком уровне предупреждений все равно не получится без вмешательства в их работу. Как по мне, `/W4` вполне достаточно :)

Comment: в eclipse (с mingw-w64)  c /Wall  все в порядке, просто я привык visual studio